# Having trouble loading json data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a file data.json contents are

```
[
{"Images" : "images/car1.jpg", "Model" : "model x", "Name" : "car a1"},
{"Images" : "images/car2.jpg", "Model" : "model y", "Name" : "car b2"},
{"Images" : "images/car3.jpg", "Model" : "model z", "Name" : "car c3"}
]
```

here is my jQuery

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function (data) {
    var columns = header(data);


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
              for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {


        $.each(data, function () {
            data[i][columns[0]] = '<img src= "' + this.Images + '" width=240 height=160>';
        });

             var cellValue = data[i][columns[colIndex]];


            if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }               
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $("#jsonTable").append(row$);
    }
});
function header(list) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var rowHash = list[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#jsonTable").append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}
```

Now my html table (id="jsonTable") Images column seems to be loading wrong data. I see only the car1 image is loading in all 3 rows of Images column...I don't see car2 and car3 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop `$.each` is not needed. Remove `$.each`

Try like this without `$.each`

```
data[i][columns[0]] = '<img src= "' + data[i].Images+ '" width=240 height=160>';
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9L913j9v/)

Comment: Thanks Anik for quickly jumping in to this, I dont see any images loading with removing the loop. doesnot seems to work.

Comment: I have added fiddle :)